# How do I pull in apache httpComponents using maven in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, apache-httpcomponents

Ok. So I'm using maven (which honestly just giving me a headache because of reasons like this).

Put this in my pom file:

[image]

maven started doing something... you know, Percentage increasing, progress bar etc lower right corner of Eclipse.

Tried to paste in code from this site so I can try out the library:
https://github.com/apache/httpcomponents-client/blob/5.0.x/httpclient5/src/test/java/org/apache/hc/client5/http/examples/ClientMultipartFormPost.java

But I get

> Cannot be resolved to a type

[image]

It ended up here in build path window.
[image]

I tried run maven clean. Did not help.
I am using Maven project. There is even a small little "M" on my project folder :)

I also found where the jars where and added them manually to webapp/WEB-INF/lib folder. That's why you see them in Classpath in picture above. I'm Using Tomcat. I believe this worked before with gson etc.

It is not often that I need to mess with Maven, so I forget in between, and then each time I spend hours, when in fact I believe it should be a simple thing to add a jar.

Surely I must be missing some common practice of how to simply add a dependency using maven in Eclipse.

I have been struggling for 2,5 hours now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need the `httpclient` artifact, as that's the resulting jar file for the repository you pulled code out of. See https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient .